# What is an elegant way to modify file in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to pass output of command to some file, on specific position.

Let's name the command **com** and output of it is:

```
auto -> 123
beta -> 456
something -> 789
```

How to pass it to file:

```
.........
blablabla

auto 
beta
something

blablabla
.........
```

Like this:

```
.........
blablabla

auto = 123
beta = 456
something = 789

blablabla
.........
```

How to do it on one line on terminal: (just example of structure)

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ com > file
```

What is an elegant way? (sed, awk, I don't know)

Comment: what is the relation between replaced items: i.e. how does `c ->` relate to `something`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest there is no relationship, it can be fixed like {(a, auto),(b,beta), (c,something)} pairs, I just want to map one to another and write it after **=**

Comment: there should be the rule of replacement - what is the rule?

Comment: let's say if it's 'a' in output of my command com, then assign it to auto, if 'c' then after "something = "

Answer (score 1):

### Make `com` create script file for *sed*

From `man sed`

```
-f script-file, --file=script-file

      add the contents of script-file to the commands to be executed
```

Make your program output rules in this format

```
s/auto/& = 123/
s/beta/& = 456/
s/something/& = 789/
```

If you are fixed on `auto -> 123` then you can modify with

```
com | sed -r 's#(\S+) -> (.*)#s/\1/\& = \2/#'
```

Then you can use it as

```
com | sed -f- file
```

or

```
com | sed -r 's#(\S+) -> (.*)#s/\1/\& = \2/#' | sed -f- file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use awk and echo directly.
Example:

Command output stored in output.log:

```
a -> 123
b -> 456
c -> 789
```

Possible one-line solution:

```
echo "$(cat output.log | head -1 | awk '{print $1}') = $(cat output.log | head -1 | awk '{print $3}')"
```

Which should result in "a = 123".

This is working if you know the exact positions of items in output.log.

You could even set a while cycle to automatically read the entire file.